# How are comments removed when they are no longer relevant?

Tags: support, comments

I see that a comment can be flagged but I take that as a function for comments that are offensive in some way.  In cases where a comment is not relevant because the question/answer has morphed in to something else, what is done to weed out comments that are no longer useful?

As example: [Crime Investigation in a fantasy world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/crime-investigation-in-a-fantasy-world/19017#19017)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag the comment as `Obsolete` (that's an option under the flag) or if all the comments on a post are obsolete, flag the post for moderator attention.  We'll clean it up.

Comment: Thank you much!