# When someone updates their post with my comment, should I remove my comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Related: [How are comments removed when they are no longer relevant?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/how-are-comments-removed-when-they-are-no-longer-relevant)

Should I remove my own comments or flag them as obsolete if my suggestion or advise is absorbed into the post on which I commented?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes; if you can remember to go back and remove them, self-deleting obsolete comments is good practice. If there are other comments on the same post that are also obsolete now, you can use a flag to mark them as obsolete as well, which signals a mod to review and (likely) remove them.